# Is it possible to access multiple cameras from ARFrame?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I have an `ARSession` using a `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` as part of its configuration. I've also enabled face tracking via:

```
configuration.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
```

In the `func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame)` delegate method, I can successfully get the `frame.capturedImage` from the world-facing camera, but it doesn't seem like there's a way to access the frame from the face-facing camera.

Am I correct in this assumption?

If so, is there some other way to access the frames of both cameras when using face and world tracking together?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### About two simultaneous ARConfigurations

As a rule, one ARSession is able to run just one ARConfiguration at a time. But there's an exception: we can use `Face` tracking config within a `World` tracking configuration. However, `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` is a "main" in that case (hence `Face` tracking is a "supplemental" config).

Both cameras (rear and front) produce 60 ARFrames per second, containing RGB, Depth, **`anchors`**, axis, feature points, etc. And each camera has its own ARFrames, what can be used for defining ***intrinsic and extrinsic ARCamera parameters*** (like 3x3 camera matrix or 4x4 transform matrix).

```
@NSCopying var currentFrame: ARFrame? { get }
```

However, in ARKit 5.0, if you are running World tracking config with activated instance property `userFaceTrackingEnabled`, you can get access only to ARFrames coming from rear camera – at the moment there's no access to simultaneous ARFrames coming from front camera.

```
let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

if ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.supportsUserFaceTracking {
    config.userFaceTrackingEnabled = true
}
sceneView.session.run(config, options: [])
    
let currentFrame = sceneView.session.currentFrame
let rearCameraTransform = currentFrame?.camera.transform
let rearCameraAnchors = currentFrame?.anchors
    
print(rearCameraTransform?.columns.3 as Any)
print(rearCameraAnchors as Any)
```

But, of course, you can control all `ARFaceAnchors` in World tracking environment.

[image]

### Tip:

In ARKit 5.0 you can use **`ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`** config on the following devices:

| TrueDepth sensor | iOS version | CPU | Depth data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| if YES | iOS11 ....... iOS15 | A11, A12, A13, A14, A15 | true |
| if NO | iOS13 ....... iOS15 | A12, A13, A14, A15 | false |

So, as a developer, you need to check whether current device supports Face tracking config or not:

```
import ARKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
        if !ARFaceTrackingConfiguration.isSupported {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "unsupportedDeviceMessage")
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful thank you!! One question - how do you use a "Face tracking config with a World tracking config" at the same time?

Comment: Yes, it's a simultaneous process in case you have face driven emojis in world-tracking scene.

Comment: Ah; what would the code for two configurations look like? Bit unclear how to set that up

Comment: There's NO case when you can use 2 configs at a time, as I said. `World`+`Face` tracking is an exceptions made by Cupertino engineers. As developers, we are not able to run two simultaneous ARConfigurations. So, there's no code for that.